# java.lang.NullPointerException for Custom accumulator

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization

I have created a Custom accumulator as below. This is serializable

```
public class ABCAccumulator extends AccumulatorV2<String, Set> implements Serializable {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet();
 @Override
    public void add(String v) {
        set.add(v);
    }
}
```

Firstly, isn't there a Spark API to create an Accumulator for any collection (like Set, Map etc, i know the CollectionAccumulator is for List) ?

Secondly, i am using this accumulator to add all values in an RDD as below:

```
ABCAccumulator acc = new ABCAccumulator ();
sparkContext.register(acc);

rdd.foreach(record -> {
acc.add(record.getName());
});
```

But when i run my code, i get an exception:

```
 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:917)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:916)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:916)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at com.def.ghi.jkl.mno.ActualClass.lambda$main$ed7564e9$1(ActualClass.java:154)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2.copyAndReset(AccumulatorV2.scala:129)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2.writeReplace(AccumulatorV2.scala:167)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteReplace(ObjectStreamClass.java:1118)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1136)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
```

Kindly help

Comment: can you please add complete stacktrace?

Comment: added full stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

I think it's failing because `ABCAccumulator` doesn't have proper implementation for all the methods.

**Try something similar:**

```
class ABCAccumulator extends AccumulatorV2<String,Set<String>> {
        Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>();
        @Override
        public boolean isZero() {
            return values.size()==0;
        }

        @Override
        public AccumulatorV2<String, Set<String>> copy() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            values.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public void add(String v) {
            values.add(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void merge(AccumulatorV2<String, Set<String>> other) {
            for(String str: other.value()){
                add(str);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Set<String> value() {
            return values;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom accumulator of your own by extending accummulatorV2 and providing proper input and output of your own, i can share an example for that from my use case.

Considering your issue i think you are using your object inside an action ie inside a forEach please make sure it is implementing serializable or else its dependencies are as it should be.This will solve your error.

Example for custom accumulator, For example, let us say you have the following user-defined map-type metric to be available post the job run:

```
case class SampleOutputStat(stats: Map[String, Long] = Map()) extends Serializable {
// method to define logic for adding metric up during a transformation 
  def add(record: String): SampleOutputStat = {
    val existingCount = stats.getOrElse(record, 0L)
    this.copy(stats = stats.filterKeys{key: String => !key.equals(record)} ++ 
Map(record -> (existingCount + 1L)))
  }
// method to define logic for merging two metric instances during an action
  def merge(other: SampleOutputStat) = {
    this.copy(hostWiseStats =  mergeMaps(left.stats, right.stats))
  }

  private def mergeMaps(l: Map[String, Long], r: Map[String, Long]): Map[String, Long] = {
    (l.keySet union r.keySet).map { key =>
      key -> (l.getOrElse(key, 0L) + r.getOrElse(key, 0L))
    }.toMap
 }
}
```

Now define your custom accumulator class as follows where it expects records of type String and consequently outputs a SampleOutputStat object which keeps track of the derived metrics you care about:

```
//Accumulator class
class CustomAccumulator(var validationAccumulators: SampleOutputStat) extends 
AccumulatorV2[String, SampleOutputStat] {

  def reset(): Unit = {
    validationAccumulators = new SampleOutputStat()
  }

  def add(input: String): Unit = {
    validationAccumulators = validationAccumulators.add(input)
  }

  def value: SampleOutputStat = {
    validationAccumulators
  }

  def isZero: Boolean = {
    validationAccumulators.isEmpty
  }

  def copy(): CustomAccumulator = {
    new CustomAccumulator(validationAccumulators)
  }

  def merge(other: AccumulatorV2[String, SampleOutputStat]) = {
    validationAccumulators = validationAccumulators.merge(other.value)
  }

}
```